# QGIS - Distance between cluster analysis not working with K means and taking to long with hierarchical method. Any advice?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, spatial-analyst, clustering

QGIS- Trying to carry out a cluster analysis regarding the density of villages in Kazakhstan.  I am placing latitude and longitude as my fields and not sure if this is correct (see image). Hierarchical method is taking too long and K mean is giving wrong results. Any advice on what I can do?

[image: Attribute based clustering plugin]

Comment: I am really not sure what is going wrong. But just to check: how many features do you have? And you are sure LAT and LONG fields are numbers and not strings (the C might mean CHAR...)?

Comment: Just checked and the data for lat long is "real", do you think integer might be more appropriate? There are ~ 4000 features. Was waiting for 30 mins for hierarchical and still nothing.

Comment: The attribute-based clustering plugin is designed for grouping points based on their attributes instead of by spatial location. It looks like you're trying to cluster your points by spatial location. There might be a better method than using this plugin with lat/long as the attributes.